# silverstripe / tinymce - stop automatic resize

Tags: silverstripe

Using Silverstripe CMS (v3.4) when I upload an image using the tinymce editor it automatically sets the width/height on the image. This causes problems such as breaking animated gifs so they don't play and also reduces the quality of static images.

How do I turn this feature off completely so that no resizing is done on upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the insert width of the images instead of them being resized to 600px wide.

**mysite/_config.yml**

```
HtmlEditorField:
  insert_width:
    1200
```

You can also override the width / height attributes on the image tag with css.

```
.typography img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Its not great but its the only work around which I know.

As for animated gifs, these are always going to break if they are resized with php.

Comment: For the first part is that the maximum width or what it'll always resize to? As for the gifs that's what I don't understand, I was using silverstripe 2.4 and animated gifs worked fine and now in 3.4 they're broken...

Comment: I just did a test with SS 3.4.1 If the image is smaller than insert_width it won't resize it larger. If it is larger, it will resize it down to insert_width.

Comment: This issue was raised last year. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/issues/1681  By reading the comments, if you don't resize the image in the editor, it works.

Comment: Woo! That worked! The image quality is much better and it also fixed the animated gifs as it was the automatic resizing that was breaking them (the users weren't resizing them).

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLEditorField` updates `img` tags in it's `saveInto` function. Inside the `saveInto` function is a `processImage` extension hook that allows us to manipulate images inserted using TinyMCE.

First we create a `CustomHTMLEditorField` extension with a `processImage` function. If the image is a gif we set the `img` `src` back to the original image path.

### SilverStripe 3

```
class CustomHTMLEditorField extends Extension
{
    public function processImage($image, $img)
    {
        if ($image->getExtension() == 'gif') {
            $img->setAttribute('src', $image->getRelativePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Next we add the extension to `HtmlEditorField` in our `config.yml` file:

```
HtmlEditorField:
  extensions:
    - CustomHTMLEditorField
```

Comment: this fixes for me on 3.6. Thanks

Comment: @3dgoo - do you know if this approach will work with Silverstripe 4?

Comment: @BaronGrivet - Looking at the SilverStripe 4 `HtmlEditorField` code the `processImage` hook no longer exists, along with the image processing in the `HtmlEditorField` `saveInto` function. Looks like we'll need to find another way in SilverStripe 4.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add images in TinyMCE… it doesn't properly support hi-dpi images and it's really hard to control the resulting layout.

Better use something like a content-block module or just use separate image-upload fields. You could also use something like the [shortcodable](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-shortcodable) module to insert media such as images via custom shortcodes.

Comment: A lot of users have images throughout their posts, how can I accommodate that if I can't use functionality that places images in their content... The content-block module adds too many steps that no one will want to do. Shortcodable looks better but from the docs it's hard to tell how easy it'll be for the user to upload and insert an image. All I really need is to disable the automatic resizing tinymce does when a user inserts an image.