# How to prevent GIFs from stopping animating when uploaded in Content area

Tags: silverstripe

When uploading animated GIFs in the content area they don't animate after the page is published.

I tried turning off resizing but that didn't work. I also tested it with Silverstripe 4 but it's the same problem.

What can I do to keep animated GIFs as they are when users upload them within the content area?

---

***Update**: Regarding the possible duplicate* - there was no solution to this problem, just a work around which didn't last long. What I need is for animated GIFs to be uploaded as they are and not meddled with by SilverStripe in any way so they continue to remain animated. This is not a CSS issue. It cannot be fixed with CSS. It is the way SilverStripe handles content that is the problem. The solution to the other question was to increase the insert width but I've done it to a high number already, going any higher seems to defeat the point of that feature, so all I want is for GIFs to be completely left alone by SilverStripe and whatever resizing feature it uses.

Additionally, there was a suggestion to make a separate upload field for GIFs, again this is not a solution. The GIFs are to be part of the article which the user creates; for example, if the article is a tutorial then the animated GIFs help the reader visually see what should be happening as they read

Comment: how did you include it in your page? In the HTMLEditor or programatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233691/silverstripe-tinymce-stop-automatic-resize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [silverstripe / tinymce - stop automatic resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233691/silverstripe-tinymce-stop-automatic-resize)

Comment: @wmk It's through the HTML Editor, there are some articles that serve as tutorials and animated GIFs help the readers follow along easier

Comment: Regarding the duplicates - They're both links to my question. I asked about this before and there was never any real solution to the problem. All I want is for GIFs to remain untouched by whatever "feature" SilverStripe has that breaks them. I tried testing it using SilverStripe 4 but apparently this "feature" remains so I didn't bother upgrading.

Comment: StackOverflow discourages asking duplicate questions, but there are other things you can do like [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the original question to draw more attention to it and attract more answers =)

Comment: So you seek for a solution to either disable image resize or exclude gifs from a resize.

Comment: @RobbieAverill Unfortunately I don't think that'll help. This CMS has very little support and small user base. I'd rather close the original question.

Comment: @wmk Yes, exactly that. The user creates the GIFs themselves, if it's too big they can resize it without a problem and reupload it. Letting the CMS take care of it is pointless if it defeats the original point- which is that it needs to be animated.

Comment: Did you try SS4.1? Some stuff changed there, but I didn't test it. In SS3 it's `HTMLEditorField::saveInto()` that's responsible for resizing images. You could subclass this and use Injector to use your onw HTMLEditorFIeld.. or just use your own field where it's needed

Comment: Have you reported this to the team? This is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a solution for this in SS4... It seems if you use the 'Replace File' option within the files section and re-upload the animated GIF that way it will not corrupt it in the same way that tiny-MCE upload does. It's a long-winded and problematic way to go about it, but at least you don't have to make any changes to your php/ss files.